# Perl Split Long Substitution Regex Over Multiple Lines

Tags: regex, perl, line-breaks, substitution

I have a very long substitution string in a Perl regular expression, which I would like to split over multiple lines.  What is the syntax to split long substitution strings over multiple lines?  I have tried the following, without success (the whitespace isn't ignored):

```
$var =~ s/(some)(thing)/A_very_long_string_with_many_characters_that_should_be_split_over_
          multiple_lines_but_can't_be_for_whatever_reason._The_matching_groups_are_"$1"_and_"$2"/x;
```

My regex replacement string is much more interleaved that this contrived example, so I can't just put the large literal portion into a variable.  In other words, the following is **not** helpful in my case:

```
my $prefix = 'A_very_long_string_with_many_characters_that_should_be_split_over_' .
             'multiple_lines_but_can\'t_be_for_whatever_reason._The_matching_groups_are_';
$var =~ s/(some)(thing)/$prefix"$1"_and_"$2"/;
```

Does anyone know of a way to split substitution strings over multiple lines?

Comment: Without a compelling argument to use the eval form of regex substitution, there is no need to use it. The rule of thumb is that the replacement side can be used as a callback, either as a direct Perl statement or a function call. Basically it says code logic has to be performed on the replacement based on the match of the regex (ie: groups). Also, using eval has some side effects to watch out for using `s///e` or even `s///ee`. Otherwise string interpolation should be adequete. The example you've shown saying `not helpful` is not true as it works just fine.

Comment: @x15 Yes, in my contrived example the *not helpful* code works just fine.  The point of adding that section to my question is because my true replacement string is something incredibly complex and interleaved, such as `$1abcd$2bcde$3cdef$1defg$2efgh$3fghi...`  In cases like this, there is no way to apply such a solution, and I didn't want a bunch of answers that addressed my contrived example, but failed to help me with my real-world problem.  I felt that adding a bunch of `$1` and `$2` variables into the long string would reduce readability, without adding clarity to the question.

Comment: Repeating, there is no reason given anywhere in the question that justifies using eval form of regex substitution. And, unless your familiar with its usage, it can be tricky and bite if done incorrectly, or for no use whatsoever. Is there something difficult to read here ? `${1}abcd${2}bcde${3}cdef${1}defg${2}efgh${3}fghi`. Compared to what ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replacement component of the `s///` operator is not a regex, and is not affected by the `/x` modifier. It is a string, similar to the contents of a double quoted string or backticks. Your only options are to construct it in a variable like you alluded to, or apply the `/e` modifier, which turns the replacement into a perl expression, in which you could construct the string, but you need to quote the parts since bareword strings are not allowed under strict.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
$var =~ s/(some)(thing)/'A_very_long_string_with_many_characters_that_should_be_split_over_' .
      qq{multiple_lines_but_can't_be_for_whatever_reason._The_matching_groups_are_"$1"_and_"$2"}/e;
```

Answer (score 6):

The replacement side is a string, subject to a few specific modifiers. A distinct case is `/e`, when the replacement side is evaluated as code instead. But if it is a plain string, then how it is evaluated isn't affected by (any?) modifiers, and surely not by `/x` since spaces count in a string.

If you use `/e` then you can write code in the replacement side as you wish and then you can form your replacement string piece-meal wise.

One way is to use a sub to neatly organize the building of the replacement string under `/e`

```
$var =~ s/(some)(thing)/build_repl($1, $2)/e;

sub build_repl {
    my ($c1, $c2) = @_;
    return 
        qq(A_very_long...) .
        qq(The_matching...$c1...$c2);
}
```